# modular forms on lattices

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

If $L=\mathbb{Z}\omega_1+\mathbb{Z}\omega_2$ is a lattice  ,
why can a weakly modular function $F$ be associated with a function $f(\tau)$defined on the upper half-plane by the formula $f(\tau)=F(\mathbb{Z}\tau+\mathbb{Z}) .$

Comment: It's because if $A\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$ is in the modular group, then $\Bbb Z A\tau+\Bbb Z$ is homothetic to $\Bbb Z\tau+\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I do not really understand the reason .

Comment: Is $F(\mathbb{Z}\tau+\mathbb{Z})=F(\tau,1)=f(\tau)$ ?